# Optional argument in AuCTeX definition of environment

Tags: latex, auctex

I want to create a style file for the `tcolorbox` environment. I have the following:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (LaTeX-add-environments
         '("tcolorbox")
         ))
      )
```

However, I want Emacs to query for the optional `[title=]` parameter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `LaTeX-env-args` function (see the [documentation](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002denv_002dargs) for more information).  In your case:

```
(LaTeX-add-environments
   '("tcolorbox" LaTeX-env-args [TeX-arg-key-val (("title"))]))
```

There are some style files using this feature, you should check them out.

If you're writing a style file for the `tcolorbox` package, I strongly suggest you to submit it to the AUCTeX mailing list so it can be added upstream.

Comment: Well, I'm queried, but the result is simply `[text I typed]`. I'll check the documentation you pointed at. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using @giordano's suggestion, and examining other styles, I managed to do this:

```
(defun LaTeX-tcolorbox-env-item-opt-label (environment)
  "Insert a `tcolorbox` environment with an optional title."
  (LaTeX-insert-environment
   environment
   (let ((label (TeX-read-string "(Optional) Title: ")))
     (concat (unless (zerop (length label))
               (format "[title={%s}]" label))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (LaTeX-add-environments
             '("tcolorbox" LaTeX-tcolorbox-env-item-opt-label))))
```